# Use static *.cshtml files in production (not *.dll)

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible in ASP.NET Core MVC keep using static *.cshtml files after publish project (not Views.dll)? I need to make changes at webhosting environment and immediately see the effect (like it was in .NET Framework ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: Nopcommerce shopping card project does this, but the way is my exact question

Answer (score 0):

You can add runtime compilation to your Views by adding the following NuGet Package to your project:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
```

And Adapting the StartUp.ConfigureServices.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

Note that this will behave bad on performance.

Comment: I meant app keep using static files from Views folder after publish it and run on hosting environment (not while develop app in debug mode)